# ERROR error TS2551: Property 'posts' does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

[image]I'm trying to run it, but it's not able to perform search results. To be specific, it's not displayed search by title.

terminal display this error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(19,11): error TS2551: Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'post'?

Please help

Data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

 searchOption=[]

 public postsData: Post[]

 postUrl: string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
   return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postUrl)
 }

 filteredListOptions() {
     let posts = this.postsData;
         let filteredPostsList = [];
         for (let post of posts) {
             for (let options of this.searchOption) {
                 if (options.title === post.title) {
                   filteredPostsList.push(post);
                 }
             }
         }
         console.log(filteredPostsList);
         return filteredPostsList;
   }

}
```

App.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post';
import { DataService } from './data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'API';

  post: Post[];

   constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    getPosts() {
     this.posts = this.dataService.getPosts()
   }


   ngOnInit() {
     this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
       this.post = posts
       this.dataService.postsData = posts
     });
   }

   onSelectedOption(e) {
     this.getFilteredExpenseList();
   }

   getFilteredExpenseList() {
     if (this.dataService.searchOption.length > 0)
       this.post = this.dataService.filteredListOptions();
     else {
       this.post = this.dataService.postsData;
     }

     console.log(this.post)
   }

}
```

App.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <div>
    <button (click)="getPosts()"> Get Posts!</button>
  </div>

    <div>

    <app-search-bar (onSelectedOption)="onSelectedOption($event)"></app-search-bar>

    </div>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Data</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async" class="group">
      <p><b>Title :</b> {{post.title}}</p>
      <p><b>Body: </b>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>


</div>
```

Search-bar.companent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { Post } from '../../post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  allPosts: Post[];
  autoCompleteList: any[]

  @ViewChild('autocompleteInput') autocompleteInput: ElementRef;
  @Output() onSelectedOption = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.allPosts = posts

    });

    this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(userInput => {
      this.autoCompleteExpenseList(userInput);
    })
  }

  private autoCompleteExpenseList(input) {
    let categoryList = this.filterCategoryList(input)
    this.autoCompleteList = categoryList;
  }

  filterCategoryList(val) {
    var categoryList = []
    if (typeof val != "string") {
      return [];
    }
    if (val === '' || val === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return val ? this.allPosts.filter(s => s.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1)
      : this.allPosts;
  }

  displayFn(post: Post) {
    let k = post ? post.title : post;
    return k;
  }

  filterPostList(event) {
    var posts= event.source.value;
        if(!posts) {
          this.dataService.searchOption=[]
        }
        else {
          console.log("not")

            this.dataService.searchOption.push(posts);
            this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
        }

        this.focusOnPlaceInput();



  }


  removeOption(option) {

    let index = this.dataService.searchOption.indexOf(option);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.dataService.searchOption.splice(index, 1);
        this.focusOnPlaceInput();

        this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
}

focusOnPlaceInput() {
  this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.focus();
  this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.value = '';
}
}
```

Search-bar.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { Post } from '../../post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  allPosts: Post[];
  autoCompleteList: any[]

  @ViewChild('autocompleteInput') autocompleteInput: ElementRef;
  @Output() onSelectedOption = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.allPosts = posts

    });

    this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(userInput => {
      this.autoCompleteExpenseList(userInput);
    })
  }

  private autoCompleteExpenseList(input) {
    let categoryList = this.filterCategoryList(input)
    this.autoCompleteList = categoryList;
  }

  filterCategoryList(val) {
    var categoryList = []
    if (typeof val != "string") {
      return [];
    }
    if (val === '' || val === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return val ? this.allPosts.filter(s => s.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1)
      : this.allPosts;
  }

  displayFn(post: Post) {
    let k = post ? post.title : post;
    return k;
  }

  filterPostList(event) {
    var posts= event.source.value;
        if(!posts) {
          this.dataService.searchOption=[]
        }
        else {
          console.log("not")

            this.dataService.searchOption.push(posts);
            this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
        }

        this.focusOnPlaceInput();



  }


  removeOption(option) {

    let index = this.dataService.searchOption.indexOf(option);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.dataService.searchOption.splice(index, 1);
        this.focusOnPlaceInput();

        this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
}

focusOnPlaceInput() {
  this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.focus();
  this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.value = '';
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `posts: any;` 
or whatever other type you want to the `app.component.ts` under `post: Post[];`

To perform the search you just probably need to change `this.post` to `this.posts` in `getFilteredExpenseList()`

```
getFilteredExpenseList() {
     if (this.dataService.searchOption.length > 0)
       this.posts = this.dataService.filteredListOptions();
     else {
       this.posts = this.dataService.postsData;
     }
     console.log(this.posts)
   }
```

You just have to add `posts: any;` 
or whatever other type you want to the `app.component.ts` under `post: Post[];`

To perform the search you firstly need to change `this.post` to `this.posts` in `getFilteredExpenseList()`

```
getFilteredExpenseList() {
     if (this.dataService.searchOption.length > 0)
       this.posts = this.dataService.filteredListOptions();
     else {
       this.posts = this.dataService.postsData;
     }
     console.log(this.posts)
   }
```

Comment: thanks, it fixed the the error message but I'm still not able to see searches

Comment: @MarinaSinko That's part I don't undestand well, could you please explain it?

Comment: @MarinaSinko It is just about putting some text to the input box and the boxes under should filter based on the value in input?

Comment: When i type title in search bar, it should display the one that matches search. I'm able to type it,  but it 's not displayed undeneath the serch bar that the one that matches the search result.

Comment: No, still the same